# How to fill an existing column with random letters and numbers in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I'd like to populate an already existing column with random values consisting of both letters and numbers. However, the distribution of letters and numbers should be the same for the whole column. I mean; it should look like that:

```
 "VWE456GT7646" (e.g. 2 letters, 3 numbers, etc.)
 "FRS765TZ9854"
 "..."
```

I thought about an UPDATE statement, but don't know how it should exactly look like.
Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

To generate a string of fixed length (example: 4) use something like:

```
DECLARE @LENGTH INT = 4;
UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn =
  SUBSTRING(REPLACE(CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(255)),'-',''), 1, @LENGTH)
```

If your requirement *the distribution of letters and numbers should be the same* means that each value has to have the same `cccNNNccNNNN` format, you can do this 4 times, stripping either characters or numbers, and concatenating these.

It will become an ugly large expression though, so you might want to rethink that requirement.

Note 1: MySQL or SQL Server? Your question has both tags. So it's either `NEWID()` or `UUID()` that you have to use.

Note 2: There is a limit to the length of the sub strings you can use, because the `GUID` has to contain that number of characters/numbers.